# Catalog Price Rule - Ignore Custom Options

Tags: custom-options, magento2.4, discount

I recently migrated over from a Magento 1.9 instance.

When we applied the catalog price rules it only discounted the price of the product and the associated custom options remained as they were (no discount). This is perfect.

However now in Magento 2.4.3.

Does it also discount the custom options? Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you found a solution for this? I have the same problem.
Kind regards,
Veerle

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/204432)

Comment: No never got this to work.